# How to migrate an admin.inc file which creates a configuration form for settings?

Tags: forms, 8, migrations

I am trying to migrate a module from drupal 7 to drupal 8, but sadly I cannot find any proper documentation on how to do this. I already re-wrote `.info` file to `.info.yml` but at this point its just a dead-end. For example I have a `admin.inc` file which creates a configuration form for settings. It looks like this:

```
function commerce_shipping_gls_settings() {
  $form = array();
  $form['rates'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Shipping costs'),
  );
  $form['rates']['commerce_shipping_gls_shipping_rate_amount'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Shipping service rate amount'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('commerce_shipping_gls_shipping_rate_amount', 3900),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer_positive'),
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

I was trying to find how to convert a config file to drupal 8, but sadly I didn't get much. Could someone please give me some guidance on how can I achieve this?

Comment: While porting or just working with d8, this page is a life saver: https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal. You'll be able to see what the code changed to and go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system_settings_form()` is replaced by `\Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase` in D8.

you can see 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1910694
[Working with Configuration Forms](https://www.drupal.org/node/2206607)

Example:

```
namespace Drupal\example_module\Forms;
use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class StudentConfigForm extends ConfigFormBase {
  // The Form ID that is used in alter hooks.
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'student_config_form';
  }
  // Configuration names that will be editable
  public function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return ['example_module.student'];
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $args = '' ){
    $config = $this->config('example_module.student');
    $values = $config->get();
    $form['student'] = array(
      '#type' => 'details',
      '#title' => $this->t('Student'),
      '#open' => TRUE,
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['student']['first_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('First name'),
      '#default_value' => $values['student']['first_name']
    );
    $form['student']['last_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Job title'),
      '#default_value' => $values['student']['last_name']
    );
    $form['student']['age'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Age'),
      '#default_value' => $values['student']['age']
    );
    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $state) {
    $values = $state->getValues();
    $config = $this->config('example_module.student')
      ->set('student', $values['student'])
      ->save();
  }
}
```